# AWS Serverless 'granteePrincipal' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[\w+=,.@:/-]+$

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, serverless

I am getting error on KMS Grants when deploying serverless from github actions.

KMSGrant ARN: `!Sub arn:aws:iam::XXaccount-idXX:role/role-name`
Error Message: `'granteePrincipal' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[\w+=,.@:/-]+$`

Is this error due to a policy or have I structured invalid ARN string? Please share the policy that I can add to fix this. Not sure about what is granteePrincipal and what is its impact?
Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

I tried to look into aws documentation but not clear about the error message and it's solution.